# Connecting to a view in bigquery using R

Tags: r, view, google-bigquery

I am trying to connect to a view in BigQuery using R-studio. I am able to establish connection and get the list of all the views however when I use

```
groups_view <- tbl(con, "users_group_view") %>% collect()
```

I get all columns with 0 rows. Can anyone please help me out on how to resolve it? When I am connecting to a table, all rows are returned but with view nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the solution. We can use the following to get the data

```
groups_view <- tbl(con, "users_group_view") %>% compute()
```